# Compare two files and print only the unmatched values UNIX

Tags: unix, ksh

I have two files suppose 1st.dat

```
a
b
c
d
```

and another file sppose 2nd.dat

```
d
e
f
g
```

my output should be like

```
a
b
c
e
f
g
```

I have tried using diff and sdiff but I am not getting the output as I mentioned. Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep

```
grep -vf 2nd.dat 1st.dat > out.dat && grep -vf 1st.dat 2nd.dat >> out.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

try `diff` like this:-

```
diff 1st.dat 2nd.dat|grep -e '<' -e '>'|sed -e  's/< \+//g' -e 's/> \+//g' > output.txt
```

> cat output.txt

```
a
b
c
e
f
g
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your version of `uniq` doesn't support the option `--unique`.
Can't harm to try:

```
cat 1st.dat 2nd.dat | sort | uniq --unique
```

This would be much easier than

```
cat 1st.dat 2nd.dat |grep -vf <(sort 1st.dat 2nd.dat | uniq -d)
```

A solution with `grep -vf` will need some more attention (matching substrings, empty lines). When you go for `grep -vf` the solution of @Daniel is easier to understand and modify, and Daniel doesn't use a slow sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `comm` command in linux, like this `comm -3 1st.dat 2nd.dat`.
It will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`diff -c file1  file2 | grep '^- \|^+ ' | tr '+' ' ' | tr '-' ' '`

file 1:

```
a
b
c
d
```

file 2:

```
d
e
f
g
```

output

```
  a
  b
  c
  e
  f
  g
```